# Blender window type icon only changes header

Tags: interface

Simple question: When I change the window type using the window type icon at the upper left corner, the only thing that changes is the header. How do I actually change the window itself?

I am using Blender 2.75 on Windows 10.

Comment: Are you refering to what's the info header in default setup?.  To view that window you  need to drag down from the bottom of  the header when you see the up-down arrow icon.  The Info window displays operator calls and other info there, which is useful to scripters and the curious.

Answer (score 2):

You probably just using wrong thing:
[image]

If you use top-left button to change window type it will only change the header, so you should use the one at the bottom left (marked in green)